# SharpDX DrawBitmap

Tags: c#, sharpdx

my project need rgba bitmap draw bitmap，Use SharpDX draw bitmap，convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap it take too long.

```
    private unsafe SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap ConvertBitmap(D2D.RenderTarget target, IntPtr userData, int size, int stride, int width, int height)
    {
        var data = new byte[size];

        fixed (byte* ptr = data)
        {
            WinApi.CopyMemory(ptr, (byte*)userData.ToPointer(), size);
        }

        SharpDX.DataStream stream = new SharpDX.DataStream(size, true, true);

        //for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        //{
        //    int offset = stride * y;
        //    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        //    {
        //        // Not optimized 
        //        byte B = Marshal.ReadByte(userData, offset++);
        //        byte G = Marshal.ReadByte(userData, offset++);
        //        byte R = Marshal.ReadByte(userData, offset++);
        //        byte A = Marshal.ReadByte(userData, offset++);
        //        int rgba = R | (G << 8) | (B << 16) | (A << 24);
        //        stream.Write(rgba);
        //    }

        //}

        stream.Write(data, 0, size);
        stream.Position = 0;

        SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat pFormat = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Ignore);
        SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapProperties bmpProps = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapProperties(pFormat);

        SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap result =
            new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(
                target,
                new SharpDX.Size2(width, height),
                stream,
                stride,
                bmpProps);

        stream.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```

1920*1080 size bitmap convert time run 00:00:00.0185530

How should I optimize performance

Comment: Question would be more meaningful if you add more benchmarks, eg for various sizes. Also check if your benchmark contains only 1 run. In that case, the 18ms you found is inaccurate due to Windows time resolution. Use the StopWatch class. Run your code 1000x and divide by 1000.

Comment: Compare your benchmark with another method. Tip: check out https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/SharpDX.DataStream/-/php-sharpdx.datastream-class-examples.html

Comment: how often does the program need to do this? 18 ms isn't really a problem. is this happening every frame?